# Translating JS script inside Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I have the following simple script from my original app and since I switched to Angular I'd like to make it work there as well.

Original script (date.js):

```
window.onload = (function() {
    var map = document.getElementById('map').contentDocument;

    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.toDateString();
    var textBox = map.getElementById('date');
    var textWrite = map.createTextNode(date);
    textBox.appendChild(textWrite);
});
```

Now, in Angular I'm trying to access the element but it returns null.
This is the component HTML:

```
<object class="mapCanvas" data="assets/canvas/map.svg" type="image/svg+xml" #map>Browser
  doesn't support SVG</object>
```

And in the component.ts:

```
  @ViewChild('map', {read: ElementRef}) map: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.map.nativeElement.contentDocument);
  }
```

How can I access the contents of the DOM element (object) and make the script work?

Comment: Can you provide Stackblitz example?

Comment: Please include your html for that component. Just with typescript doesn't provide enough information since you are trying access DOM

Comment: Now it's included :)

Comment: Your code is fine for getting the element from the template?

Comment: Pretty sure contentDocument is for iframe? Don't see iframe on your html

Comment: contentDocument is for object. The script works fine outside Angular, with pure HTML/JS implementation